# Real-time scrolling Google LineChart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Following from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612313/scrolling-linechart-animation-with-google-charts?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) question, I'm trying to implement a scrolling Google LineChart. The chart displays 10 seconds worth of data (calculated as 10 * the period of each data update), and prepends the DataTable with zero values on initialisation to fill in the required 10 seconds worth of data.

The plot runs continuously at 20Hz (50ms period), whereby the first visible data point is removed and a new data point appended, such that the total number of data points (data.getNumberOfRows()) is constant. I'm close to achieving this functionality, but as the fiddle below shows, I'm overlooking a few things. The new point is plotted and connected to an earlier point, not the second final point, and the number of visible data points grows over time.

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {
'packages': ['corechart']
});

google.setOnLoadCallback(loadChart);

function loadChart() {

    var options = {
        width: 1000,
        height: 400,
        vAxis: {
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 100
        },
        curveType: 'none',
        pointSize: 5,
        series: {
            0: {
                color: 'Blue'
            }
        }
    };

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'X');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Data');

    data.addRows([
        [0, 0]
    ]);

    var interval = 50;
    var dataSize = data.getNumberOfRows();
    var plotSize = (10 * ((1/interval) * 1000));

    if (dataSize < plotSize) {
        for (i = 0; i < (plotSize - dataSize); i++ ) {
            data.addRows([[i, 0]]);
        }
    }

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('google_chart_div'));
    setInterval(drawChart, interval);

    function drawChart() {
        for (i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfRows() - 1; i++) {
            data.setValue(i-1, 1, data.getValue(i, 1));
        }
        data.insertRows(data.getNumberOfRows()-1, [[data.getNumberOfRows()-1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1 ]]);
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
}
```

[Fiddle example code](http://jsfiddle.net/dhmoxa4v/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised I should just be resetting the X values each iteration as per the following code which works as desired.

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {
    'packages': ['corechart']
});

google.setOnLoadCallback(loadChart);

function loadChart() {

    var options = {
        width: 1000,
        height: 400,
        vAxis: {
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 100
        },
        curveType: 'none',
        pointSize: 5,
        series: {
            0: {
                color: 'Blue'
            }
        }
    };

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'X');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Data');

      data.addRows([
          [0, 0]
      ]);

      var interval = 50;
      var dataSize = data.getNumberOfRows();
      var plotSize = (10 * ((1/interval) * 1000));

      if (dataSize < plotSize) {
          for (i = 0; i < (plotSize - dataSize); i++ ) {
              data.addRows([[i, 0]]);
          }
      }

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('google_chart_div'));
    setInterval(drawChart, interval);

    function drawChart() {
        data.removeRow(0);
        for (i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
            data.setValue(i, 0, i);
        }
        data.insertRows(data.getNumberOfRows(), [[data.getNumberOfRows()-1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1 ]]);
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
}
```